# ContinuE thE sequencE (+1)

Tags: knowledge, number-sequence

Find the correct pattern and continue the following sequence

`4, 3, 4, 7, 6, 5, 2, 6, 8, 7, 3, ...`

You should be able to find at least one hint in the title

---

**EDIT**

Just realized I made a little mistake. It is still a valid sequence, but I need to give a hint, because it would be too arbitrary without this one.

> The sequence will never contain a number greater than 8

---

**Hint 1**

> Further explanation of the initial hint, you will need `mod 9`

**Hint 2**

> `switch (i mod x) {...}`

**Hint 3**

> In 1748 you were able to continue this sequence to the <del>23th</del> 24th number

**Hint 4**

> The title might be a hint on (not only) a important number used in this puzzle, even it's not there in its true form

**Hint 5**

> The sequence is based on a number

**Hint 6**

> A hint on how you could create the sequence with some kind of pseudocode (addition to hint 2)
>
> ```
> for (i = 0; i < basenumber.length; i++)
>      switch (i mod x) {...}
> ```

**Hint 7**

> $2 * 2 = 4, 7 * 3 = 21, 1 * 4 = 4$

Comment: Ah, cr*p. I was about to ask exactly what you already changed about of 1748.

Comment: @Racso yeah I was a bit in a rush when I wrote this hint :D

Comment: I think I got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence continues:

> $2,0,0,7$

This is because:

> $\text{e}=2.71\;828\;182\;845\;904\dots$.
>
>  Your sequence is $2a_0, 3a_1, 4a_2, 2a_3, 3a_4, 4a_5, \dots \pmod 9$.
>
>   So $4,21,4,\;16,6,32,\;2,24,8,\;16,12,20,\;18,0,16 \dots \pmod9$
>  $ \to 4,3,4,\;7,6,5,\;2,6,8,\;7,3,2,\;0,0,7\dots$

Comment: @user477343 actually he was the first to suggest this answer, so he will be awarded :D

Comment: @IanFako oh, well, okey then. I'll delete my comment. $(+1)$ :)

Answer (score 4):

I might have the answer, although it could be a coincidence

After reading your edit:

> I suspected the answer might be found using modular arithmetic, specifically `mod 9`

No lightbulb yet, but I thought:

> Perhaps I can combine the digits into 2-digit numbers and the remainder after `mod 9` might be of interest

Then I noticed:

> Skipping the first number, the next two form 34, then 76, 52, 68, 73
>  I found that:
>  34 = 4 * 9 + 8
>  76 = 8 * 9 + 4
>
>  Surely there is a mathematical term for it, but let's call them 'inverse modulo's' for now :)
>
>  This also holds for the next two numbers:
>  52 = 5 * 9 + 7
>  68 = 7 * 9 + 5
>
>  That just leaves
>  73 = 8 * 9 + 1
>  and our answer
>  1 * 9 + 8 = 17
>  Meaning the next two numbers are 1, 7

Comment: Interesting, that this works up to this point. I checked if it holds for the next couple of numbers but it seems to stop after the last `3` in the sequence. Anyway +1 for the effort

Comment: Thanks for checking the remainder of the sequence. Could have been an artefact of the actual sequence, but now I know to keep searching

Answer (score 3):

Answer: If I'm correct, the first digits of the sequence are one of the following:

> 43476526873290716319
>
> 43476526873200716310

The second one takes into account the "mod 9" rule.

Here's the algorithm I used:

> Take each digit of e = 271828182845904523536 (decimal separator removed) and its position i = 0, 1, 2... That means (2,0), (7,1), (1,2), (8,3), ...
>
> Calculate d[i]*(i%3+2). That means:
>  
>
>  2*(0%3+2) = 2*2 = 4
>  
>  7*(1%3+2) = 7*3 = 21
>  
>  1*(2%3+2) = 1*4 = 4
>  
>  8*(3%3+2) = 8*2 = 16
>
> Add the digits of each answer together. That leads us to 4, 3, 4, 7, ...

TL; DR:

> Multiply each digit of e (including the whole part) by 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, ... and add the digits of the result.

Comment: I'd say you're pretty close ;)

Comment: correct now but JonMark Perry was faster, +1 anyway

Answer (score 2):

> I would assume this is part of the pattern:
>
>  Six consecutive numbers: A,B,C,D,E,F
>
>  A = some number
>  B = A + x
>  C = A + B
>  D = C - 1
>  E = D - x
>  F = E - A
>  (next A = F)
>
>  I just don't know the rule for x..
>
>  But I think for the solution I don't need to know x.
>  Applying my pattern to your given numbers I would get `1` as the next number.

Comment: A can't see how your solution matches even the first few numbers. Can you please illustrate your algorithm with the specific numbers from the puzzle?

Comment: I just assumed the given numbers are in the following order:  
 E,F/A,B,C,D,E,F/A,B,C,D,E,...  

Therefore the last given number (3) would be E, and the next numbers would be F/A,B,C,D,...  

(keep in mind A and F label the same position in my solution)

Comment: In order to convince me that this is correct, you're going to need to define the heuristics for `x`. You should also explain the hint provided in the title and its relation to your solution.

Comment: @IanMacDonald That's why I used x: I just don't know the heuristics for `x`.
I also don't understand the hint in the title. I assume with the hint it should be possible to define the rules for `x`.

Comment: Sorry you're on the wrong track ;)

Comment: Please also read the edit I made to the post, that was my bad

Answer (score 2):

I think I got the hint in the title.

> The capital letters in the title are E,  E,  E and + 1 which when read is 'three E plus 1', which is equal to 4. I think it gives a hint as to how the first term is derived for the sequence.

Comment: Not bad, this is partially correct

Answer (score 2):

Partial Answer

So clearly going by the hints and the title the sequence is based off the number

> e

Because

> The title has E capitalized multiple times. Euler calculated e to the 23rd digit back in 1748.

This is where I'm stuck...

Comment: So far so good ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just notes to myself.

> I have a feeling that the the title could mean either 15 or 16 (since E=5 in alphabet). Otherwise, it might mean 1555 (as in hint 3 you suggested a year). 
> Another find from the title is that the words have 8 3 8 letters, and the sequence starts with 4 3 4. Probably does not have to do with anything though.

From hint 2:

> Switch..case should change logic based on module of previous number, could be mod 2, mod 3 or something else. Checked a couple of ideas, no luck so far.

From hint 3:

> I suspect that 2018 is somehow of use here.

Finally,

> Tried combining numbers, since it seemed promising: 43   34  47  76  65... Results of division by 9 were 4(+7) 3(+7) 5(+2)   8(+4) 7(+2). For a moment I thought that next number is created by the division and mod, but didn't work out for now. Maybe there is something here.

Will continue gnawing on this puzzle.

Comment: I like the way you try to solve this. Not quite there yet but not bad. And a little reminder, you can solve all my puzzles without hints (unlikely but not impossible :D)